# Output MySQL Query Results to Combo Box

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following snippet wherein I'm wanting to grab all entries from SMSGateway and place them in a combobox in my page:

```
<?php 
$querycarrier="SELECT * from 'SMSGateway'";
$resultcarrier=mysql_query($querycarrier);
if (!$resultcarrier) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($rowcarrier = mysql_fetch_array($resultcarrier)){
    echo "<option value=$rowcarrier[GatewayName]</option>";
}
?>
```

Currently, the SMSGateway table is empty.  So, when I view the page in question, I receive the following error:

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SMSGateway'' at line 1
```

How can I be sure that the error is being thrown because the table is empty?

Thanks much for yuour help and guidance.

Comment: Try unquoting the table name.  I know its unnecessary, dont know if would cause a problem.  its worth trying tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$querycarrier="SELECT * from SMSGateway";
```

remove single quotes - if you need to something use ` char left from 1 on keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes around table name.

edit. Beware when you don't use quotes around option value and options contain spaces. Text would be truncated to the first word.

This is safer and a more correct syntax.

```
echo "<option value=\"$rowcarrier[GatewayName]\"</option>";
```

Comment: Hi bensiu. You always come first ;)